# Writing a valid copy constructor for a hash map in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, hashmap, copy-constructor

I'm having some trouble creating a copy constructor for my hash map class right now. Currently, I understand how to do a copy constructor for arrays, by copying things over from the original array to the next. For example, here is what would be done for an array list:

```
ArrayList::ArrayList(const ArrayList& a)
    : items{new std::string[a.cap]}, sz{a.sz}, cap{a.cap}
{
    // arrayCopy is a for loop that does items[i] = a.items[i] on each iteration
    arrayCopy(items, a.items, sz);
}
```

I understand that we need to initialize values to a new array list, and copy them over to a new list of arrays. However, I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around doing this to a separately chained hash map.

In my HashMap.hpp file, I have an unmodifiable structure, like this:

```
struct Node
{
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
    Node* next;
};
```

I need help understanding how to put each node into my copy constructor. This is my copy constructor, without the actual "copying" code:

```
HashMap::HashMap(const HashMap& hm)
   : hashTable{new Node*[hm.amountOfBuckets]}, amountOfBuckets{hm.amountOfBuckets}, sz{hm.sz}
{
}
```

How would I accomplish properly iterating through each hash table index, and creating a new node depending on how many there are in the original table? Would I have to create four Nodes, two to keep track of the new table, and two to keep track of the original table?

I tried to implement this and also tried to implement a way to copy over values within a do while loop. This is my code (that doesn't work and completely sucks :( )

```
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < amountOfBuckets; i++) {
        // target
        Node* newHead = hashTable[i];
        Node* newCurrent = newHead;
        // source
        Node* head = hm.hashTable[i];
        Node* current = head;
        do{
            newCurrent = new Node();
            newCurrent->key = current->key;
            newCurrent->value = current->value;
            newCurrent->next = current->next;
            newCurrent = hashTable[i];
        } while(newCurrent != nullptr);
```

With this I run into segmentation faults. I'm really not quite sure how to properly copy over each value into the new hash table? Or how I should go about linking it all together?

Here is the declarations for HashMap.hpp

```
#ifndef HASHMAP_HPP
#define HASHMAP_HPP
#include <functional>
#include <string>
class HashMap
{
public:
    typedef std::function<unsigned int(const std::string&)> HashFunction;
    static constexpr unsigned int initialBucketCount = 10;
public:
    HashMap();

    // This constructor instead initializes the HashMap to use a particular
    // hash function instead of the default
    HashMap(HashFunction hasher);

    HashMap(const HashMap& hm);
    ~HashMap();
    HashMap& operator=(const HashMap& hm);

    void add(const std::string& key, const std::string& value);
    void remove(const std::string& key);
    bool contains(const std::string& key) const;
    std::string value(const std::string& key) const;

    unsigned int size() const;
    unsigned int bucketCount() const;
    double loadFactor() const;
    unsigned int maxBucketSize() const;


private:
    // This structure describes the nodes that make up the linked lists in
    // each of this HashMap's buckets.
    struct Node
    {
        std::string key;
        std::string value;
        Node* next;
    };
    // hash function gets stored in here
    HashFunction hasher;
private:
    Node** hashTable;
    unsigned int amountOfBuckets;
    unsigned int sz;

public:
    unsigned int getTableIndex(unsigned int hashVal) const;
};
```

And here is my (incomplete) code for HashMap.cpp. Also, I will not be using the hash function currently in the namespace. I just used it as an easy way to predict bucket indices to test my add/remove functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "HashMap.hpp"

namespace {
    unsigned int easyHashFunc(const std::string& key) {
        unsigned int hashValue = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
            int letterIndex = key.at(i);
            hashValue += letterIndex; // just add up the letters
        } // end for
        return hashValue;
    } // end easyHashFunc
}

HashMap::HashMap()
    : hasher{easyHashFunc}, hashTable{new Node*[initialBucketCount]()}, amountOfBuckets{initialBucketCount}, sz{0}
{
}

// constructor that initializes HashMap to use a different hash function other
// than the default
HashMap::HashMap(HashFunction hasher)
    : hasher{hasher}, hashTable{new Node*[initialBucketCount]()}, amountOfBuckets{initialBucketCount}, sz{0}
{
}

HashMap::HashMap(const HashMap& hm)
   : hashTable{new Node*[hm.amountOfBuckets]}, amountOfBuckets{hm.amountOfBuckets}, sz{hm.sz}
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < amountOfBuckets; i++) {
        Node* newHead = hashTable[i];
        Node* newCurrent = newHead;
        // source
        Node* head = hm.hashTable[i];
        Node* current = head;
        do{
            newCurrent = new Node();
            newCurrent->key = current->key;
            newCurrent->value = current->value;
            newCurrent->next = current->next;
            newCurrent = hashTable[i];
        } while(newCurrent != nullptr);
    }
}


// destructor: deallocate the HashMap
HashMap::~HashMap()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < amountOfBuckets; i++) {
        Node* nextNode = hashTable[i]; // store each hashtable list in a bucket node
        while(nextNode != nullptr) {
            Node* deleteCurrent = nextNode; // set current to the bucket node (head)
            nextNode = nextNode->next; // delete current is on the first node, update head to second node
            delete deleteCurrent;
        } // end while
    } // end for
    // once done, delete hash table
    delete[] hashTable;
} // end destructor

// Assignment operator that overloads equals
HashMap& HashMap::operator=(const HashMap& hm)
{
    // incomplete
    return *this;
}

void HashMap::add(const std::string& key, const std::string& value)
{
    // Check if key being stored matches key already in hashmap
    unsigned int hashedValue = hasher(key); // get hash value (unmodified by buckets)
    unsigned int tableIndex = getTableIndex(hashedValue); // get the table index
    // case 1, check to see if current is nullptr, meaning our first node
    // is the one we should use, ie. we don't need to traverse the list
    if(contains(key) == true) { // if key is already in the hashtable
        return; // exit program
    } else { // otherwise, key is not in the hash table
        Node* head = hashTable[tableIndex];
        Node* current = head;
        if(current == nullptr) {
            // nothing in bucket
            // create a new node
            current = new Node();
            current->key = key; // set username
            current->value = value; // set pw
            current->next = nullptr;
            hashTable[tableIndex] = current;
            return; // exit
        } else {
            do {
                current = current->next; // advance to next node
            }while(current != nullptr);// end while
            // currently at node we want to insert key/value at
            current = new Node();
            current->key = key; // set key(username)
            current->value = value; // set value (pw)
            current->next = head;
            hashTable[tableIndex] = current; // set next to point to nullptr
        } // end inner if-else (creates node)
    } // end outer if-else
} // end add

// takes in a key (username), removes it and the value (password) associated
// with it, otherwise, it has no effect
void HashMap::remove(const std::string& key)
{
    unsigned int hashedValue = hasher(key);
    unsigned int tableIndex = getTableIndex(hashedValue);
    if(contains(key) == false) { // could not find key in bucket
        return; // do nothing
    } else {
        Node* prevNode = hashTable[tableIndex];
        Node* delNode = prevNode;
        if(prevNode->key == key) { // first one is a match
            hashTable[tableIndex] = prevNode->next; // set the head of the hash table to point to the next node
            delete delNode;
            return; // exit
        } else { // otherwise, we must loop through and find the node we want to delete
            do{
                // check for match, if found, break out of do while
                if(delNode->key == key) {
                    break;
                }
                prevNode = delNode; // save current node in previous
                delNode = delNode->next; // point the searched node to the next node
            }while(delNode != nullptr); // end do while
            // set the previous node to point to delNodes next node
            prevNode->next = delNode->next;
        } // end inner if-else
        delete delNode; // de-allocate
    } // end outer if-else
} // end remove()

// returns true if given key is in hash map, otherwise returns false
// this acts as a find method
bool HashMap::contains(const std::string& key) const
{
    unsigned int hashedValue = hasher(key); // hash the key given to get an index
    unsigned int tableIndex = getTableIndex(hashedValue); // get the table index
    Node* current = hashTable[tableIndex];
    // iterate through each node in the linked list
    // start at first node (this is current)
    while(current != nullptr) {
        if(current->key == key) {
            return true; // found match, exit
        }
        current = current->next;
    } // end while
        return false; // we haven't found a match
}

// value() returns the value associated with the given key in this HashMap
// if the key is stored in this HashMap; if not, the empty string is returned.
std::string HashMap::value(const std::string& key) const
{
    if(contains(key) == true) { // found match
        unsigned int hashedValue = hasher(key); // hash the key given to get an index
        unsigned int tableIndex = getTableIndex(hashedValue); // get the table index
        Node* current = hashTable[tableIndex];
        while(current != nullptr && current->key != key) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        return current->value; // return value after traversal
    } else {
        return ""; // no match, return empty string
    }
}

unsigned int HashMap::size() const
{
    return sz;
}

unsigned int HashMap::bucketCount() const
{
    return amountOfBuckets;
}

double HashMap::loadFactor() const
{
    return sz / amountOfBuckets;
}

// return the table index for a given hashvalue
unsigned int HashMap::getTableIndex(unsigned int hashVal) const {
    return hashVal % amountOfBuckets;
}
```

Comment: well, include your HashMap class declaration into the post, I need to see its members in order to offer any help.

Comment: @Anonymous added the declarations and definitions

Comment: I hope this answer will give you an overall idea on how should it work. I didn't compile it nor test it.

Comment: You need to traverse the list for each bucket. Think about it as going down the buckets vertically and then for each bucket you need to go horizontally through your list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HashMap::HashMap(const HashMap& hm)
{
    amountOfBuckets=hm.amountOfBuckets; 
    hashTable= new Node* [amountOfBuckets];

    for (int i=0; i<amountOfBuckets; i++)
    {
        Node* n = hm.hashTable[i];
        Node** p = &hashTable[i];
        *p = NULL;
        while (n)
        {
            Node* c = new Node(*n); // node copy constructor, should set n->next to null
            *p = c;
            p=&c->next;
            n=n->next;
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want Node copy constructor replace Node* c = new Node(*n); with:

```
        Node* c = new Node;
        c->key = n->key;
        c->value = n->value;
        c->next = NULL;
```

Comment: Just so I'm understanding this, what do n, p and c represent? Does n represent a node at the current bucket index for the original hash table? p represents a reference to the new hash table? And then you dereference p to null so that each head of the list is null? From there c is the copied node so to speak which you then set values for, and store back into p?

Comment: n is source Node being copied, c is its copy, and p is pointer onto previous element's next pointer.

Comment: Note that p initially points to the bucket. So when first node of it is beign copied, new node's pointer is stored in bucket. In next iteration p will point to previously copied node's next pointer.

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot more sense now.