# Understanding what a double pointer to a reference does C++

Tags: c++, arrays, list, pointers, copy-constructor

I'm having issues understanding my teachers example of a copy constructor for an array that has a linked list attached to each index. I understand some of the concepts with it, but I don't understand what some of the terms mean, or specifically what exactly is being referenced.

Here is my teachers copy constructor code:

```
ListChain::ListChain(const ListChain& lc)
   : arrayTable{new ListNode*[lc.arraySize]}, arraySize{lc.arraySize}
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        ListNode* source = lc.arrayTable[i];
        ListNode** head = &arrayTable[i];
        *head = nullptr;
        while(source != nullptr) {
            ListNode* copy = new ListNode(); // create new node to store data into
            copy->key = source->key;
            copy->key = nullptr;
            *head = copy;
            head = &copy->next;
            source = source->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the structure for the ListNode (along with the private implementation for the arrayTable):

```
struct ListNode {
    std::string key;
    ListNode* next;
};
```

I understand that by creating a pointer to a pointer for arrayTable (`arrayTable**`) should let me create the array of lists that I want. However, why would we set the head to the address of the table we are copying our key value into (`ListNode** head = &arrayTable[i]`)?

Why do we need to do this? And what is it actually doing for our ListNode?

Inside the while loop, I understand that we create a ListNode called copy which will store each value transferred from the source ListNode, and then we store it in the head. The question I have is what does `head = &copy->next` do? And how does it make our copy constructor work?

Maybe I just need someone to outline what is happening in a single loop of the program, because I'm not seeing it :(

Thanks!

Comment: See this post and the answer and comments to answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096794/writing-a-valid-copy-constructor-for-a-hash-map-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `head` initially points to the head of the bucket.
2. `*head = nullptr;` initializes the bucket to be empty.
3. then after the first node is copied, its pointer overwrites this null value:

   ```
   *head = copy;
   ```
4. `head` is then changed to point to the 'next' field in the copied node:

   ```
   head = &copy->next
   ```
5. so all lately copied nodes pointers are stored in previous elements' `next` field
   forming a linked list:

   ```
   *head = copy;
   ```