# Copy Construction For hashMap in C++

Tags: c++, hashmap, copy-constructor

In the recent assignment, we are asked to implement a hashmap in C++ without the techniques provided in STL.

I'm stack on one of the functions -- copy constructor. After searching the google, I found a valid solution in the question:

[Writing a valid copy constructor for a hash map in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096794/writing-a-valid-copy-constructor-for-a-hash-map-in-c?answertab=active#tab-top)

But I can't totally understand it. Could anyone please help explain 
1. why we need to use a pointer-to-pointer `Node** p = &hashTable[i];` ?
2. what is the logic in the while loop?
3. especially, what does this code `p=&c->next;` mean?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there are many different types of hash table implementations, so any specific one you find online may or may not yield insights into what you'll need to do for your own implementation.  That said...

1. `p` is initially pointed at the *head* element for the bucket, which is the `Node*`s at [`this->`]`hashTable[i]`.  It's initially used to set it to `NULL`.  As you're dealing with `Node*`s, a `Node**` is a natural way to keep track of their locations.
2. each iteration of the `while` loop duplicates the next `Node` that's in bucket `[i]` in `hm`; the duplicate is created in new memory at `c`, and `*p` (which tracks the linked list positions being created for the `*this` object under construction) is updated to point thereto.
3. `p=&c->next;` means `p` is set to the `next` member of the newly created `Node` (at address `c`): that `next` pointer must be initialised by the `Node(const Node&)` constructor to `nullptr`/`NULL`/`0`, or the linked lists created wouldn't terminate properly.  Only if there are more elements in the linked list of colliding elements to be copied, the next iteration will overwrite `*p` and therefore the `next` member of the previously added `Node` with the next value of `c`.

Summarily, you're looking at a loop that copies `amountOfBuckets` linked lists.  If you're not familiar with linked list operations, you'd be better off writing a linked list class first and getting that working, then use it to help implement the hash table.